# Moving Entity Framework projects

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have developed a project using entity framework on my local machine. What I am wondering is what is the best way to move the project to live server. Do I need to recreate the entities on the live server, if tables are same? Or I need to change the connection string? Reason why I am asking is that on live server I might not have access to the Visual Studio to re create entities. 
I searched around cant find what I am looking for. Appreciate your comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create the database and objects on the server manually. You could export the DB schema to a SQL script through Management studio.

Also ensure that you get rid of the `DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges` strategy, which might be the case on your development environment- especially if you are using rapid prototyping.

If your connection string is externalized to web.config, donot forget to change that as well.